# How to run linux program in java under windows?

Tags: java, windows, linux, emulation

How can I run linux binary under windows? Is there some emulation jar or something to run linux program under windows from java program code like Runtime.getRuntime().exec()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases tool like cygwin can help you. 
BTW if you wish to run windows program under linux you can use wine.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're asking if you're able to run a random Linux binary (ie, not a Java program built under Linux) under Windows, the answer is simple - no, not without building it as a Windows executable.

You should be able to run a 100% Java program on Windows and Linux unless you're making use of libraries that aren't available on both OSs.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely impossible for arbitrary (non-Java) programs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a virtual machine with linux installed inside of windows.

Comment: I expect rather answer about use JPC to emulate, because virtualization is so obvious

Answer (score 1):

This not possible unless it's binary of an interpreted language (like Java binary). Also looks completely imposable to write a 'converter' between OSes: even slight difference in design of the OSes cannot be converted as it becomes necessary to write 'logic' converter!?? 
(not even mentioning the numerous Unix implementations) Think of this: if to linux process means different thing from what it means to windows then how would this get converted ?:) It's not only syntactical but most importantly a logic difference which hurdles possibility of having what you need exist already.